# ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970)] handshake failed

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Хотела сделать парсер из ютуба в телеграм, но что-то пошло не по плану. Сначала всё шло хорошо, код справляется с поиском видео, находит их, но не отправляет пользователю. В качестве ошибки выдает [12128:6196:0331/180951.868:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно с этим сделать

````
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
 
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("")
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['search_videos'])
def search_videos(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите текст, который вы хотите найти в YouTube")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, search)
 
 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ты что-то хотел?")

 
def search(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Начинаю поиск")
    video_href = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + message.text
    driver.get(video_href)
    sleep(2)
    videos = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
    for i in range(len(videos)):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, videos[i].get_attribute('href'))
        if i == 1:
            break
 
 
bot.polling()```
````